# Angular typeahead using service

Tags: angularjs, service, typeahead

When I use a service, that returns a promise, typeahead doesn't work... In [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nWUukFbObMiLrJjS2RRS?p=preview) is possible to see the error...

Using the first method (getLocation), the example works ok... but, when I try to use a service, as implemented in getLocation1, that returns a promise, it fails:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> ```
> at ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js:3638
> ```

It's like the promise returned by the $q service wasn't the same kind of object returned by the method "then" from $http.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to return the promise in the second example.

```
var futureGoogle = GoogleService.getAddresses(val);
futureGoogle.then(
    ....
```

needs to be replaced by

```
var futureGoogle = GoogleService.getAddresses(val);
return futureGoogle.then(
    ....
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AJvjDSjJaoNuCJzf60yw?p=preview) is the working plunker

Comment: thanks boindiil... this is exactly what was happening... fresh eyes always works... ;-)